# Hipervincular una celda con más de una URL indicada en la misma

Tags: formularios, google-apps-script, formato

He creado una hoja de cálculo con Google Sheets vinculada a un formulario(Google) que tiene 2 campos: uno del tipo "desplegable" y el otro del tipo "subir archivo". Cuando incluyo un solo archivo, se indica correctamente la url del mismo de forma hipervinculada y accedo a él sin problema desde la celda. Pero si incluyo más de un archivo se vuelcan todas las url´s separadas por comas en la celda y  no tiene el formato de hipervínculo.
Mi consulta: ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el formato de cada url (sin cambiarlas de celda) para que cada una tenga el formato de hipervínculo y pueda acceder a su página?
Hice una función para separar los textos delimitados con comas (uno por cada url subida) y luego darle formato, pero quería evitar la creación de más columnas (una por cada url recogida).

He modificado mi código. Esta vez he conseguido a través de substring, separar las url de la celda para poder darle formato de hipervinculo a cada una de ellas. He conseguido que se haga en la primera y lo escribe en la celda D1, pero en el resto, ya no sé qué hacer.No funciona los setRichTextValue(RichTextValue); Algo estoy haciendo mal con.

```
 function mySplitV() {
     var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
     var cell = sh.getActiveCell().getValues()[0];
     var sCell = cell[0].split(",");
     var indexes = [];
     var myLinks = "" + sCell + ""

   console.log('Mis urls: ' + myLinks) // Datos por celda
   console.log('Número de datos a separar: ' + sCell.length); // Muestra el 
   número de datos separados por comas que tiene la celda
   console.log(myLinks.length) // 12 caracteres contando comas en el caso de 
   AAAA,NNN,KKK

   for(var i=0; i<myLinks.length;i++){
   if(myLinks[i] === ',') indexes.push(i);
   }
   var data1 = myLinks.substring(0, indexes[0])
   Logger.log(data1)
  
   var RichTextValue=SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue() // Hipervincula 
   primera url
   .setText(""+ data1 +"")
   .setLinkUrl(0, indexes[0], "" + data1 + "")
   .build();
    sh.getRange("D1").setRichTextValue(RichTextValue);

    for(var j=0; j<sCell.length-1;j++){  
    var data = myLinks.substring(indexes[j]+1, indexes[j+1])
    Logger.log(data)

   var RichTextValue=SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue() // Hipervincula 
   siguientes url
   .setText(""+ data1 +"")
   .setLinkUrl(indexes[j]+1, indexes[j+1], "" + data1 + "")
   .build();
   }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como has visto el formato automático de hipervínculos funciona únicamente cuando el texto es un hipervínculo y no cuando el texto incluye múltiples hipervínculos (independientemente del separador utilizado).

Actualmente las hojas de cálculo de Google permiten dar formato a partes del texto tanto de forma manual como usando Google Apps Script o la API de Google Sheets.

Para hacerlo manual,

1. Pon la celda en modo de edición (por ejemplo, haz doble click en la celda)
2. Repite de 2 a 5 para cada URL

   1. Selecciona un URL
   2. Copia el URL
   3. Oprime <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. Esto abrirá el editor de enlaces
   4. Pega el URL en la casilla correspondiente, si lo deseas edite el texto y oprime OK / Aceptar.
3. Aplica los cambios (por ejemplo presiona <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Para usar Google Apps Script / Google Sheets API deberás familiarizarte primero con los métodos de Class Range más específicamente con [setRichtTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue)

Comment: Perfecto, la primera parte manual, me funciona correctamente. La opción  de setRichtTextValue, he leído varios artículos sobre como dar formato de hipervínculo a cada url, entiendo que los próximos pasos que debo planificar son: 1. Poder seleccionar cada url por separado (.setText('url1, url2...) y 2. Aplicar a cada una mediante setRichTextValue el formato de hipervínculo  ¿Correcto?

Comment: 1. Leer los datos, 2. Separar los URLs, 3. Construir los RichTexts 4. Escribir los RichTexts

Comment: Por cierto, favor de leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hola, he editado mi consulta. Ahora con nuevo código logrado, pero no consigo el objetivo

Comment: Como la pregunta ya cuenta con una respuesta, en lugar de editarla lo apropiado es que publiques una nueva pregunta.